# Comparing two objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having problems comparing two objects and have probably stared myself blind on it. Problem is, that even though the orderConfigResultArray[i] and shoppingCart[k] contains different variables, it keeps going into the else sentence. Console.log below the code, thanks for any help! :)

Code below:

```
for (i=0; i < orderConfigResultArray.length; i++) {
        if (shoppingCart.length !== 0) {
            console.log("Shopping cart er ikke 0");
            for (k=0; k < shoppingCart.length; k++) {
                if (orderConfigResultArray[i].type !== shoppingCart[k].type && orderConfigResultArray[i].length !== shoppingCart[k].length && orderConfigResultArray[i].height !== shoppingCart[k].height && orderConfigResultArray[i].grit !== shoppingCart[k].grit && orderConfigResultArray[i].cut !== shoppingCart[k].cut) {        
                    createOrderSelection(orderConfigResultArray[i].type, orderConfigResultArray[i].length, orderConfigResultArray[i].height, orderConfigResultArray[i].grit, orderConfigResultArray[i].cut);
                    shoppingCart.push(orderConfigResultArray[i]);
                } else {
                    console.log("_____________");   
                    console.log("Pre-existing config");
                    console.log(orderConfigResultArray[i]);
                    console.log(shoppingCart[k]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Shopping cart er 0");
            createOrderSelection(orderConfigResultArray[i].type, orderConfigResultArray[i].length, orderConfigResultArray[i].height, orderConfigResultArray[i].grit, orderConfigResultArray[i].cut);
            shoppingCart.push(orderConfigResultArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4KK3.png)

Comment: why post a picture of the console.log - copy/paste

Comment: replace `&&` with `||` ?

Comment: Holy cow dude. Use a loop over `Object.keys` or use a library for deep equality or something.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin OP read about the "Explicit is better than implicit" rule and explores its limits ;)

Comment: don't reinvent it just reuse it. http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual